# gnuplot is it possible to make addition of time value

Tags: gnuplot

who cant tell me how to make an addition of time in gnuplot.

I am trying to do this :

```
StartTime="09:23:20"
EndTime="12:45:34"
Delay="00:03:23"

Action=StartTime + Delay
```

or

```
set xrange [("10:23:45"+Delay): EndTime]
```

But it is not working as i expect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnuplot stores time values internally as a floating point number. The functions to convert back and forth between this and a formatted representation of time are strptime("timeformat", "mytime") and strftime("timeformat", sec).  So you want something along the lines of

```
Start_sec = strptime("%H:%M:%S", StartTime)
Delay_sec = strptime("%tH:%tM:%tS", Delay)
Action_sec = Start_sec + Delay_sec
ActionTime = strftime("%H:%M:%S", Action_sec)
```

Note that the delay is an time interval, not a date or time-of-day, so it needs a different format.  See the documentation under "help time_spec". Or you could just provide as a number of seconds

```
Action_sec = 123.4
```

Comment: Hello Ethan, it is exatly the solution, many thanks, it works also fine with the delay in second.

Comment: @Aelurus Please accept Ethan's answer if it solved your problem. Thanks